# In firestore rules, how to convert int value to string with left padding zeros?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In firebase rules, I am converting a month to 2 char string to access a document.

For eg, when converting `let var = string(3)` I want to get `"03"`. Instead I get 3.

I can't locate anything for zero padding in https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md

How to convert int value to string with left padding zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a simple way for zero padding. For now, I added a check on string length and concatenating a `"0"`.

```
let d = string(3);
let dd = (d.size()==2 ? d : "0"+d);
```

Here `d.size()` is not 2, so `dd` will be assigned `"03"`